# Changed password, access token invalid

Tags: facebook, passwords, token

Website feed to facebook pages is broken and I get the following message:

```
"message":"Error validating access token: The session has been invalidated 
  because the user has changed the password.",
"type":"OAuthException","code":190,"error_subcode":460
```

Similar questions already been asked but I notice some of them are quite old and I want to make sure the answer is up to date.

Can I resolve the error without reapplying for a new token?

Answer (score 9):

I fixed this by going to the related app in Facebook Developer center and resetting the Facebook App Secret (even reauthorizing would not work).  It is the only way I could fix it and very frustrating and ridiculous that because the user changes their login password that it breaks the API/app.

Answer (score 4):

No, you need to reauthenticate the user. See here: <strike>[Handling Invalid/Expired Access Tokens](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/access-token-expiration/)</strike>
[How-To: Handle expired access tokens](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2011/05/13/how-to--handle-expired-access-tokens/) .

Comment: That's a dead link... not only does FB provide the worse documentation in the history of API documentation, they move pages that may contain useful information and provide no ability to find the new page.

Answer (score 1):

There is also an outstanding bug which is causing this issue for many users. Please subscribe so that it gets the attention it needs :-)

https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/284696814962357

Comment: Has this been fixed? Because the Facebook bug issue page says it has, but I'm still getting this issue. My access tokens expire within an hour.

Comment: I am using the September 2012 version of the Android Facebook SDK and I'm still getting this error.

Comment: It has been fixed, then broken, then fixed and broken again I think - the answer is usually to get the user to delete your app and completely reauth it.

This seems to reliably fix the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I notice you haven't accepted an answer so I thought I would try and help out. I was experiencing a similar problem and this answer worked for me https://stackoverflow.com/a/12654266/32348

Answer (score 1):

You get this message because you have probably changed your password of your Facebook account. On the other hand, your instagram account password remained the same. The easiest way is to change your instagram password. Click to setting in instagram app, click reset the password. The program will probably send you a reset password link. Do it. Re-connect your instagram with your new password. The app will ask you to continue with your Facebook account and you in this way have re-given permission to instagram to publish ads. You are ready to go!

Happy ads.

Answer (score 1):

This happened to me using {SNAP} Social Networks Auto Poster because the password to my Facebook Account was changed.

Steps to resolve:

- Delete the complete social account set in {SNAP} Settings menu (Re-authorization will not fix the issue, as suggested by snap customer support)
- Go to developers.facebook and change your APP Secret.
- Start fresh and Create a New Social Account in {SNAP} with your APP ID and your new APP Secret.

That should do it.