# com.facebook.sdk error 2 in ios

Tags: ios, facebook-graph-api

When choosing not to allow a 'Connect' to a Facebook app, I'm stuck with Facebook throwing "com.facebook.sdk error2." errors at me, even after re-installing my app.

Is this a bug in the Facebook SDK or am I missing something?

I have gone through all post available as well as few bugs on developer.facebook.com, i have also made some changes in my code as per advice but still my users are reporting same issue.

I have followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12620760/choosing-not-now-when-accepting-app-causes-com-facebook-sdk-error2) similar question but no solution.

Comment: double check your app id?

Comment: appid is coorect, you can check it in screenshot

Comment: for safety reasons, do not share the app id with some one... just was asking a question..

Comment: in my app setting i have enable facebook login and deep linking, is this causing this issue?