# Can't get a new access token using native iOS 6 login with 3.1 SDK

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-ios-sdk

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Facebook SDK 3.1 - Error validating access token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12601191/facebook-sdk-3-1-error-validating-access-token)

In my app I have a delete account option. When used it tells our server to delete the account and it removes the app from the user's App Center. I also call [[FBSession activeSession] closeAndClearTokenInformation]. Even if I delete the iOS application and reinstall it I continue to get the old access token which obviously doesn't work since the Facebook app doesn't even exist any more. This is happening when I'm using native login in iOS 6 through the new SDK. The only way I can get a fresh/working token is to go into the Settings.app and disable Facebook access to my app then reenable it. At that point I finally get a new token (as well as an alert asking the user if they want to give the app permission to open).

How can I really clear/reset the token that iOS is holding onto?

Comment: I'm also experiencing this same issue in the case of using multiple devices with the same account. Logging in from device 2 invalidates the access token of device 1 but device 1 never attempts to get a new token so it is doomed to fail.

Comment: Please see the answer to this issue from Jason Clark as it applies here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12601191/facebook-sdk-3-1-error-validating-access-token/