# Error validating access token: User XXX has not authorized application YYY

Tags: objective-c, facebook

I am trying to handle permissions errors and basicaly I removed the app from www.facebook.com App Settings.
In the app I am using this method to login:

```
[FBSession openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions:nil allowLoginUI:YES
completionHandler:^(FBSession *session, FBSessionState    status, NSError *error) {
```

For some reason the token is cached and the app is not realizing that I removed the permissions from the web.
So after the openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions the sessions always is open, then I make a request and I get the next response: (not in the error object but in the response):

Error validating access token: User XXX has not authorized application YYY.

So I handle it and because the token is not valid I do this:

```
[[FBSession activeSession] closeAndClearTokenInformation];
```

And try again to login, but same issue.

Seems that if a user removes permissions from web the party is over forever??
Any way back?

Comment: Normally if you are redirecting to facebook for auth token it will ask the user to authorize the app again.

Comment: have a look at this:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12601191/facebook-sdk-3-1-error-validating-access-token