# iOS 6 Facebook Login not refreshing access token

Tags: iphone, objective-c, facebook, ios6, facebook-access-token

Nothing I'm reading (many FB dev articles and SO question) is helping, so I thought I'd post here. I'm trying to get this all to work with iOS 6 and Facebook SDK 3.1.1.

I've got a pretty basic setup: My iOS app authenticates with Facebook, I pass the access_token to my server and the user is now logged into my app. The only other thing they can do related to facebook is post something to their wall. I'm using the legacy Dialog window so the user can add their own comments.

Everything works perfectly on a new install for the first hour or so. If the user is logged in via the iOS Settings app, they're presented with a quick iOS confirmation box, I get their token, send it to my server and we're all good.

If I paste the token I receive into Facebook's Access Token debugger, it shows that it will expire in an hour.

If I wait that hour and come back to the app afterwards, anything I try to do gives me this error:

```
{"error_code":190,"
  error_msg":"Error validating access token: 
              Session has expired at unix time 1351497600. 
              The current unix time is 1351525180. }
```

1. What do I need to do so things just work? [I've read](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12601191/facebook-sdk-3-1-error-validating-access-token/) that in SDK 3.1.1 FBSession will just take care of it, but that doesn't seem like the case. My access token is expiring, and once it does, iOS/FB SDK won't give me back a refreshed one.
2. Even logging out (which calls `[FBSession.activeSession closeAndClearTokenInformation]`) doesn't fix this. The only thing I've been able to do is "Reset Content and Settings" in the iOS Simulator Preferences, re-enter my FB credentials in Settings.app, and rebuild my app. Only then can I get another token which will expire in an hour.

Random notes:

1. When my app resumes, I'm calling `[FBSession.activeSession handleDidBecomeActive]` and `[self.facebook extendAccessTokenIfNeeded]`
2. According to the SO question linked to above, the SDK should automatically be calling `FBSession#renewSystemAuthorization`. I've put an NSLog in there, and I never see that method getting called.

**UPDATE #1**:

I mentioned that I've read that the SDK will handle invalid/expired tokens. It seems like that should happen in FBRequestConnection#completeWithResults:orError:. See inline comments for notes about the code path.

```
- (void)completeWithResults:(NSArray *)results
                orError:(NSError *)error
{
    int count = [self.requests count];
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        FBRequestMetadata *metadata = [self.requests objectAtIndex:i];
        id result = error ? nil : [results objectAtIndex:i];
        NSError *itemError = error ? error : [self errorFromResult:result];

        id body = nil;
        if (!itemError && [result isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]) {
            NSDictionary *resultDictionary = (NSDictionary *)result;
            body = [FBGraphObject graphObjectWrappingDictionary:[resultDictionary objectForKey:@"body"]];
        }

        ...

        // *******************************************
        // My code actually falls into this block, proving that I do in fact have an invalid session
        // *******************************************
        if ([self isInvalidSessionError:itemError
                        resultIndex:error == itemError ? i : 0]) {
            [metadata.request.session closeAndClearTokenInformation:itemError];

            // *******************************************
            // Unfortunately metadata.request.session is nil, so this condition is never
            // run, so renewySystemAuthorization is never called
            // *******************************************
            if (metadata.request.session.loginType == FBSessionLoginTypeSystemAccount){
                [FBSession renewSystemAuthorization];
        }
    }

    ...
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that's a long-lived access token?  What does the expiration date say when you enter the token into the [Debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug).   My long-lived tokens say "Expires: 1356716436 (in about 2 months)"

Comment: Huh, that's very interesting. Good idea. Plugging it into the debugger (for those that don't know: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug) says "Expires: 1351540800 (in about an hour)". I feel like I've followed the SDK docs and examples very closely. My app works great within that first hour, but after that, I just can't get a renewed token. Any ideas?

Comment: Could you provide info about your App Dashboard settings. What's your setting in the Advanced > Authentication section as an example. Anything else that's different from the docs that you can think of in your settings?

Comment: Good question. They all seem to be normal. For Advanced > Auth, I have Web as type and blank for callback url. I'm thinking it needs to stay Web and not Native/Desktop because our website uses the same FB app. I tried switching it to Native/Desktop today, and when I plugged the token in to the debugger, there was no expiration time. Seemed weird to me so I changed it back. Everything else is Disabled or blank except for Social Discovery, Picture as Dict, and Reset Client URL is set to NO. In Basics, I have "Native iOS App configured correctly, with FB Login enabled, and Deep linking disabled.

Comment: @djibouti33 - I have the same issue, which I describe here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13242787/having-trouble-with-facebook-ios-sdk-v-3-1.  Did you arrive at a solution?  I'm considering a few but not certain yet of the best approach.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This isn't the type of fix I was after, but things look to be working as expected, so at this point I just need to ship.

First things first, it turns out that old versions of our app were requesting offline_access. I did not know that. I went in to my FB app's Settings > Advanced, and enabled "Remove offline_access permission." I am now getting back a token that lasts two months ([check out the facbeook token debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug)).

Now that I'm getting back the correct kind of token, I still have a problem with getting back a valid token when it has been deactivated/expired. Since I'm now getting back a 2 month token, I can't wait for that to expire, so my plan was to trigger an OAuthException by going into my account's settings and deauthorizing it.

In my appDidBecomeActive, I put [FBRequestConnection startForMeWithCompletionHandler:nil] to simply trigger a silent request to FB, and when that fails because of an invalid session/token, the code flow runs through the correct path and [FBSession renewSystemAuthorization] ends up getting called, which is ultimately what I was needing. What this allows iOS to do is the next time I go to Log in to my app through FB, iOS prompts me again, understanding I don't have a valid token anymore. Calling [FBSession renewSystemAuthorization] effectively tells iOS that the next time my app requests access, hit facebook and give me back a new/refreshed token.

For the most part everything is working as expected now.

Comment: Where do u find "FB app's Settings > Advanced, and enabled "Remove offline_access permission."" I can't find it

Comment: hmm, looks like that's been removed. some searches show it's being deprecated/removed in the next month or so, but perhaps if it wasn't enabled to being with, they just hide it completely. try skipping that step and following the rest and see where that gets you.